# How do I execute os.system() with multiple arguments

Tags: python

I want to execute the `os.system()` command with multiple arguments.

```
def playmp3(SongName, Freqency):
    os.system("sox -t mp3", SongName, "-t wav - | sudo pifmrds -freq", Freqency, "-audio", SongName)
```

But I always get this error:

```
>>> playmp3("/home/pi/music/hit_the_street2.wav", "105")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in playmp3
TypeError: system() takes exactly 1 argument (6 given)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot. You have to compose your command line yourself, for instance using `format`:

```
os.system('sox -t mp3 "{0}" -t wav - | sudo pifmrds -freq "{1}" -audio "{0}"'.format(SongName,Frequency))
```

note the `0` and `1` notation which allows to use a parameter more than once.

and protect your arguments with quotes when you don't know if they contain spaces.

BTW this is really an obsolete way to perform system calls. That's quick & dirty but 2 `subprocess.Popen` calls chained together and controlled argument passing would be much cleaner, like this:

```
proc1 = subprocess.Popen(["sox","-t","mp3",SongName,"-t","wav","-"],stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
proc2 = subprocess.Popen(["sudo","pifmrds","-freq",str(Frequency),"-audio",SongName],stdin=proc1.stdout)
proc2.wait()
```